# Linq Queries abstraction with expressions, which way is better?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable

We've been looking for a nice approach to querying our database, focusing on both ease of development, readability and business rules compliance.

I've found two interesting articles on the internet that describe similar but slightly different approaches, one is using a Query Object and Expressions, and the other is using mainly extension methods with business relevant intentions and ultimately expressions as well.

1. [Query Object approach](https://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/08/02/query-objects-with-repository-pattern-part-2/)
2. [Extension Method approach](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/giving-clarity-to-linq-queries-by-extending-expressions/)

Here's some example code that we could have (inside the repository) for both cases:

```
public IEnumerable<ControlOverview> GetRoutineControlOverviewsForTest(string testId, DateTime dateOfInterest)
    {
        var controlOverviewQuery = new ControlOverviewQuery()
                                           .ForTest(testId)
                                           .ForLotUsage(ControlLotUsageStatus.Routine)
                                           .ForControlStatusAt(dateOfInterest)
                                           .ForControlConfigurationAt(dateOfInterest)
                                           .ForControlLotConfigurableAt(dateOfInterest);

        return this.Context.ControlOverviews.Where(controlOverviewQuery.AsExpression());;
    }
```

second case:

```
public IEnumerable<ControlOverview> GetRoutineControlOverviewsForTest(string testId, DateTime dateOfInterest)
    {
        return this.Context.ControlOverviews.ForTest(testId)
                                            .ForLotUsage(ControlLotUsageStatus.Routine)
                                            .ForControlStatusAt(dateOfInterest)
                                            .ForControlConfigurationAt(dateOfInterest)
                                            .ForControlLotConfigurableAt(dateOfInterest);
    }
```

As you can see, from the developer perspective it's more or less the same. Same for readibility. The only thing that is different is the implementation detail (extension methods vs query object)

In my team there are divided opinions on using one or the other, and I can't find a good set of arguments (pros/cons) to go in favour of one approach or the other.

I personally prefer the first approach (query object), since i'm OOP guy and like the builder pattern that it uses, but I cannot find a better argument than that in order to not use extension methods.
I'd highly appreciate some insight here. Perhaps this is just a coding preference and it's difficult or just not possible to say that one is certainly better than the other with a strong argument

Comment: Both "toys" break immediately when you want to use brackets... `A && B` is doable... `A || B` is doable... But `(A || B) && C`?

Comment: The main drawback that I hear from the query object approach is that why do we need to create an extra "layer" when we can just use the provided interfaces (IQueryable) from the framework (which can be accomplished easily via extension methods)

Comment: xanatos : i think this is another improvement which can be done for both approaches via expression trees

Comment: The syntax becomes a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, these are the important Pros

**Query Approach**

- Since the methods are in fact class methods, they can access internals and in particular, the access can be restricted. Thus, you can force developers to use the query object rather than custom LINQ. This ensures consistency and maintainability, but degrades flexibility
- You gain the flexibility of using polymorphism. In the article that you have linked, this is not featured, but it may get important as soon as you start using different query class implementations, for example to get a uniform access to data of different sources with different schemas

**Extension Methods**

- You can use it with interfaces. In fact, I use extension methods most often to implement standard members for interfaces and I think this is where they are most useful. However, this only makes sense if you have some predefined interfaces such as e.g. already available in the platform as for example `IQueryable`. If you are using your own classes where you have full control over it, this point is pretty weak.
- Slightly better conciseness (I know, not that much, but I'd say it matters)

Comment: *Thus, you can force developers to use the query object rather than custom LINQ.* This if he hides the `Context` and splits the method that builds the query from the method that has the Context and executes it.

Comment: Or that could be made explicit by having a ToQueryable method on these objects. At least then it's known what's expected and customized behavior.

Comment: Thanks Georg for the list. I still don't see though a really strong point clearly favoring one or the other. I think in the end it's just a matter of preference, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer slightly the first approach, because it doesn't hide the fact that there is a `IQueryable<>` (the `this.Context.ControlOverviews` isn't "hidden" by calling a chain of other methods), so if you want to chain an addition `.Where()` or an additional `.Select()` it is clear you can d oit.

Comment: I don't get it. You can also do it with the second approach, which is basically extending the Where extension method to work on the ControlOverview collection type and return another IQueryable which can also be chained

Comment: @DanielPerez If you look at the second query, you don't know that each one is returning a `IQueryable<>`... You can't be sure, because you can't see the return type. It is "opaque". The first one is very clear: here is the builder, here the builder and the `Context` mix.

Comment: yeah, that's true. But that's what the defenders of this approach say is an advantage =D

Comment: @DanielPerez Note that the first one is impossible to use with `Join`, while the second one is usable even with joins (but only a little)

Comment: @DanielPerez No... You don't "slightly" hide information: you remove it (encapsulating everything) or you make it easily visible.